# org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am getting:

```
 org.testng.TestNGException: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.initialize(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:136)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:97)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I am working on writing automation scripts using maven, testNG and selenium. when I execute my TestCases individually through RunAs-> TestNG, they execute fine . But when I try to run all the Test Cases as a suite by doing: right Click on Testng.xml-> RunAs TestNG suite. I get the above exception.

I have tried various options so far, like upgrading the TestNG version(now using 6.10.0), importing the project again, changing the POM and TestNG files. Nothing has worked so far.

I tried to Google this but could not find the answer for this issue. whatever solution is given online corresponds to SSL connection and I am not sure that that's my issue.

Can anyone please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

The issue seems to be with the testng.xml. Make sure the first line of .xml file should be exactly as:
`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">`

the only issue here is "http" to be used instead of "https"

Comment: I had the problem with additional space at the end:
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
after change to 
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
was working again 
Thanks for Hint

Answer (score 0):

Even i have faced similar issue but for me I have missed adding testNg library in my project build path, check and see if it helps.