# Maven TestNG with SureFire plugin: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I am trying to tun my tests with TestNG Maven and SureFire plugin, but getting following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project Demo: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\ihorh\Workspace\Demo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:665)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
```

`......`

If I am running without maven (just test.ng file) everything successful. Or If I delete  following block from pom.xml :

```
<build>
          <plugins>
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
              <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
```

Comment: It seems that maven was looking for certificate ` `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. Try to look at reports and dump files in `C:\Users\ihorh\Workspace\Demo\target\surefire-reports`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem but I also got when trying to run the testng.xml file.
I removed the following line: 
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Actually it it also works when you change the https to http as well.

Comment: found something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339698/org-testng-testngexception-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertpathbuilderexc